# Does the bundle identifier for an OSX or iOS App matter?

Tags: xcode

Can the bundle identifier be something like `cmp.cmp`, or does it have to be `com.something`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be globally unique at the App Store. So in my case if I do

com.maniac-games.LowDown

I know that nobody else probably has this identifier since I'm the only Maniac-Games around.

Comment: Does it mean i have to a web page for it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But you do need a "support URL" to give to the submission process. As an example, mine is http://www.maniac-games.com/support.html

Comment: You mean i can do something like this cmp.cmp?

Comment: What happen you don't have a web site?

Comment: You must have a support URL to give them.